DBContext Configuration is generating a configuration error
I'm trying to use this DbContext in a POST method to add a record.
The constructor of the controller with this method is as follows:
public CookieController(ILogger<CookieController> logger, ICookieRepository cookieRepository)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _cookieRepository = cookieRepository;
}

Here is the method:
[HttpPost(Name = "")]
public IEnumerable<Cookie> PostCookie([FromBody] Cookie data)
{
    DbContextOptions<ReactWithASPDbContext> options = new DbContextOptions<ReactWithASPDbContext>();

    ReactWithASPDbContext dbContext = new ReactWithASPDbContext(options);

    // ...
}

The DbContext class looks like this:
public class ReactWithASPDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ReactWithASPDbContext(DbContextOptions<ReactWithASPDbContext> options): 
        base(options) 
   { 
   }

   // ...
}

This is the Program.cs code:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ReactWithASPDbContext>(options => { 
    options.UseSqlServer(

builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:ReactWithASPDbContextConnection"]);
});
var app = builder.Build();
DbInitializer.Seed(app);

This is the DbInitializer method, and it works:
public static void Seed(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)
{
    ReactWithASPDbContext context = 
         applicationBuilder.ApplicationServices
                           .CreateScope()
                           .ServiceProvider
                           .GetRequiredService<ReactWithASPDbContext>();

    // ...
}

The appsettings.json has this content:
"ConnectionStrings": {
   "ReactWithASPDbContextConnection": "Server= 

(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=ReactWithASP;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
}
But the configuration is generating this error:

No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

I'm assuming that I do not need to recreate the init stuff in the Program.cs file that creates an IApplicationBuilder etc. There should be a way to pass along the context once its created right?

Erk, that's not how most people would make their controller aware of a db context to use in their PostXxx method

Why does your DB Initializer "work" when you still haven't configured anywhere what connectionstring the context should use? Are you saying that Seed does correctly seed the right DB with data?

The seed method works yes.

I see you've just posted the bit of code that looked missing before... Post the constructor of your controller (the class that contains PostCookie method)

Just added the constructor

OK,  does ICookieRepository have a constructor that has this context as a parameter? Or maybe does the controller have a property that is the DB context decorated with an injection attribute? (It looks like you've done the necessary setup for DI to create a context for you, wired up to a DB, but I haven't yet seen where you inject it into the controller by DI)

The CookieRepository class has this constructor:
public CookieRepository(ReactWithASPDbContext reactWithASPDbContext)
{
_reactWithASPDbContext = reactWithASPDbContext;
}

OK, so in your PostCookie mthod you wouldn't create an instance of the context, you'd call methods on the cookierepo and the cookie repo would use the injected context to perform DB work. Don't do DB work in the controller if you have a repo that does db work that the controller is supposed to call on (and if you have a service layer, don't do repo work in the controller)

It tells you that you have not added something like this
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectionString);
}

as in
public class SomeContext: DbContext
{

    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public SomeContext(string connString) : base()
    {
        _connectionString= connString;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectionString);
    }

    // Add DB sets here

}


And the connString is the name of that variable in appsettings.json right?  Doesn't that have to be initialized?  Also is that in place of the current constructor?  Or in addition to it?

Pull that data out of config in your startup, where you configure your DI and the rest of your services, and call AddDbContext. Use DI to pass an instance of the context to your controller's constructor or injected props, and use it. Do not retain your context for a long time (don't do stuff that causes it to become singleton)

I'm sorry but could you show me an example?  This is the only way I saw it done in the example I used.

@John How you store conn string, is up to you. If you store in appsettings - fine. We store in the secret manager. Also, about DI. There is another answer shows how to do it using DI. That is one way,.  There is another way, where you instead of .Services.AddDbContext use normal .AddTransient and you can add db context factory. Then in your controller you can call context like using (var ctx = CtxFactory.Create()) { // do something  } . I use factory style because it helps with supporting multiple DB engines by one code base.

you need to configure your DbContext in Program.cs

// You already have this
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args); 

// But you are missing this
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ReactWithASPDbContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer("name=ConnectionStrings:ReactWithASPDbContextConnection"));

Once that is done, you need to inject ReactWithASPDbContext in your controller instead of creating it manually
public CookieController(ILogger<CookieController> logger, 
ICookieRepository cookieRepository, ReactWithASPDbContext context)
 {
  _logger = logger;
  _cookieRepository = cookieRepository;
  _context = context;
 }

  [HttpPost(Name = "")]
  public IEnumerable<Cookie> PostCookie([FromBody] Cookie data)
 {
  _context.DoSomething()
  ... 
 }



It's there.   I added it to the example.

@John updated based on your latest edits

No, this is mixing layers. If the OP is having a repo layer and the repo has context you wouldnt also use contexts from controller. That's creating a mess. If one was writing extension methods for contexts, and accepting that a context is a repo pattern implementation (reasonable) then (absent a service layer) have the context in the controller by all means, but don't have both repos that have contexts and also then have contexts in controllers

I see what you're saying but the approach above works.  But not very maintainable I take it?

I take it you mean that the Add functionality should be in the Repo class?

The question I'm trying to solve is how to get the dbcontext to work. From there, definitely look at different patterns (like repository) that would help organize the code, but that goes way beyond the scope of the original ask.

OK I implemented it using the Repo and it works.  Thanks!!

how to get the dbcontext to work - it already works ;) it just needs using where it has been setup to work, rather than injecting/creating all over the place :D But not very maintainable I take it? - in a couple of years you'll look back an be amazed at how your engineering approach has evolved. That's a good thing

you mean that the Add functionality should be in the Repo - yes. The repo is responsible for presenting the underlying data store as a consistent interface. One day you might decide to swap to keeping data in a text file or facading an API as if it were a DB. You rewire your repo to save in a text file instead. Add carried on working but it writes to a text file or saves to drop box etc, everything carries on calling it none the wiser that data is going to a different place. You can make your repo implement an IBlahRepo interface that demands Add exists. You can write a fake repo..

..for testing purposes, that just stores data in memory, nice and fast, easy to destroy. It behaves just like your real repo. You can write tests for it, and call them and prove the code that relies on Add will work, without trashing your DB. This is why we create separated layers with uniform interfaces; so we can swap them out for something else without disturbing the rest of the setup

Actually, on that testing note, I do recommend that you use something that is close to a repo that uses a real context, but perhaps performs a rollback at the end of each test. It means you can test your operations on a real DB with all the variances it introduces, but it reliably undoes its work after it proves its point, meaning your perfectly curated test data isn't harmed and is ready for another test
